# Find the projection of vectors to a plane not equal to 0 (in R^3)

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

this is my first post on math stack exchange, so pardon me if I do not write something right.

I am wondering how one would proceed to project a vector in R^3 to a plane in R^3 such that the plane's equation is $Ax+By+Cz = D$ where D is not equal to 0. In class, we learned to find the basis of a plane, and calculate the projection matrix from it. However, since the plane in the scenario above does not even contain the $0$ vector, it is not a vector space, and thus the basis is meaningless.

For example, if I were to try to project the vector $<1,2,3>$ to the plane $2x + y - z = 3$, how would I go about solving it?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How familiar are you with affine subspaces? (Also, welcome to MSE!)

Comment: I've heard about them - being 'shifts' of planes going through the origin (subspaces), but I do not know much about them.